# Calculate Column Percentages within factor levels

Tags: r, split, lapply

I am trying to find the column percents for each level (Level_1 and Level_2), within each row (V1, V2, V3, V4).

This is my data:

```
DF <- read.table(text=
"F1     V1  V2  V3 V4

Level_1 2   10  9   9   
Level_1 7   3   6   7   
Level_1 10  7   7   3   
Level_2 5   6   2   3   
Level_2 4   6   1   6   
Level_2 1   10  3   4"  , header=T)
```

I want output that looks like this:

```
F1      V1  V2  V3  V4

Level_1 11% 50% 41% 47%

Level_1 37% 15% 27% 37%

Level_1 53% 35% 32% 16%

Level_2 50% 27% 33% 23%

Level_2 40% 27% 17% 46%

Level_2 10% 45% 50% 31%
```

This is my code so far:

```
col_percent <- unsplit(lapply(split(DF, DF$F1), function(x) prop.table(as.table(as.matrix(x[ , 2:ncol(x)])), 2)), DF$F1)
```

When I run it I get these warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In x[i] <- value[[j]] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In x[i] <- value[[j]] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

The code does get me the column percentages that I want, but it outputs them as one vector of numbers. Can anybody help me figure out what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use this:

```
lapply(split(DF[, -1], DF$F1), function(x) t(t(x) / colSums(x)))

$Level_1
         V1   V2        V3        V4
1 0.1052632 0.50 0.4090909 0.4736842
2 0.3684211 0.15 0.2727273 0.3684211
3 0.5263158 0.35 0.3181818 0.1578947

$Level_2
   V1        V2        V3        V4
4 0.5 0.2727273 0.3333333 0.2307692
5 0.4 0.2727273 0.1666667 0.4615385
6 0.1 0.4545455 0.5000000 0.3076923
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split the data frame, perform the operation using `lapply`, and the combine the data frames to the final output.

```
DF_list <- split(DF, f = DF$F1)

DF_list2 <- lapply(DF_list, function(x){
  x[, -1] <- lapply(x[, -1], function(y) paste0(round(y/sum(y) * 100), "%"))
  return(x)
})

DF2 <- do.call(rbind, DF_list2)
rownames(DF2) <- 1:nrow(DF2)
DF2
#        F1  V1  V2  V3  V4
# 1 Level_1 11% 50% 41% 47%
# 2 Level_1 37% 15% 27% 37%
# 3 Level_1 53% 35% 32% 16%
# 4 Level_2 50% 27% 33% 23%
# 5 Level_2 40% 27% 17% 46%
# 6 Level_2 10% 45% 50% 31%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by` from `dplyr` to do this:

```
df >%>
  group_by(F1)>%>
  mutate(V1_pct = V1/sum(V1),
         V2_pct = V2/sum(V2),
         V3_pct = V3/sum(V3),
         V4_pct = V4/sum(V4)
  ) >%>
  ungroup()
```